# Ajax запрос внутри div-a сформированного другим ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Суть вопроса. 
Есть div, который формируется на основе ajax-запроса. Отправляется form с параметрами и на их основе получаю ответ - Форму с чекбоксами и кнопку "Сохранить"

index.php:

```
<div class="1">
    <form id="get_tasks_form"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="obname" value="Name1">
    <input type="hidden" name="obid" value="333">
    <div class="paddingBottom">
    <input type="button"  class="btn btn-default"  id="btnObject333" value="Name1">
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="objectinfo">
<p>DIV куда выводится ajax</p>
</div>
```

ajax-кнопка:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#btnObject333').click(
function(){
sendAjaxForm('objectinfo', 'get_tasks_form', '/core/ajax/ajax_monitoring.php');
return false; 
});
});
```

Функция sendAjaxForm-

```
function sendAjaxForm(result_form, ajax_form, url) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:     url, //url страницы (action_ajax_form.php)
        type:     "POST", //метод отправки
        dataType: "html", //формат данных
        data: jQuery("#"+ajax_form).serialize(),  // Сеарилизуем объект
        beforeSend: funcBefore,
        success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
            result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            document.getElementById(result_form).innerHTML = result;
        },
        error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены
            document.getElementById(result_form).innerHTML = "Ошибка. Данные не отправленны.";
        }
     });
```

На данный запрос мне Ajax-ом возвращается такая форма:

```
<form method="POST" id="savePform">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="checkbox" name="pz" id="task_pz" value="1" checked="">
<label class="bg-success" for="task_pz">Пояснительная Записка</label>
</div>  
<div class="form-group">
<input type="checkbox" name="pl" id="task_pl" value="1" checked="">
<label class="bg-success" for="task_pl">Планы</label>
</div>  
<div class="form-group">
<input type="checkbox" name="fs" id="task_fs" value="1">
<labelfor="task_fs">Фасады</labelfor="task_fs">
</div>  
<div class="form-group">
<input type="checkbox" name="razrez" id="task_razrez" value="1" checked="">
<label class="bg-success" for="task_razrez">Разрезы</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="checkbox" name="boxnotuse" id="notuseid" class="notuse" value="1">
<label class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" for="notuseid">Том не нужен</label>
</div>            
<input name="task_id" type="hidden" value="1817">
<input name="pos_num" type="hidden" value="3">
<input name="object_id" type="hidden" value="79">
<div class="form-group text-right">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnsaveP" value="Сохранить">
</div>
</form>
```

Далее я в этом же ответе пишу обработчик для кнопки "Сохранить" по аналогии с первой кнопкой:-

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
$('#btnsaveP').click(
function(){
sendAjaxForm('objectinfo', 'savePform', '/core/ajax/ajax_save.php');
return false; 
});
});
```

Ожидаю что `<div class="objectinfo">` заменится ответом из `ajax_save.php`, однако при нажатии просто перегружается страница `index.php`
Как правильно реализовать второй ajax запрос для сохранения изменений в чекбоксах?

Answer (score 0):

`objectinfo` - это `class`, а не `id`.

```
function sendAjaxForm(resultSelector, ajaxFormId, url) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url:     url, //url страницы (action_ajax_form.php)
    type:     "POST", //метод отправки
    dataType: "html", //формат данных
    data: jQuery("#" + ajaxFormId).serialize(),  // Сеарилизуем объект
    beforeSend: funcBefore,
    success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
        result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        document.querySelector(resultSelector).innerHTML = result;
    },
    error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены
        document.querySelector(resultSelector).innerHTML = "Ошибка. Данные не отправленны.";
    }
  });
}

sendAjaxForm('.objectinfo', 'get_tasks_form', '/core/ajax/ajax_monitoring.php');
```

Hе говоря уже о том, что html вопроса не содержит элемента с `id="btnObject0"`.

Comment: Крайне извиняюсь, что ввел в заблуждение. Конечно же это `id="objectinfo"`  Это я тут ошибся пока писал. Все поправил.
И кнопку тоже поправил)

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема была в моей невнимательности, и добавлении обработчика кнопки `'#btnsaveP'` в неправильно место.
В итоге. Обработчик кнопки имеет вид:

```
$(document).on("click" , "#btnsaveP", function(e) {
    sendAjaxForm1('objectinfo', 'savePform', '/core/ajax/ajax_mon_save.php');
});
```

И добавлен в файл с js-кодом, который загружается при обращении к index.php, а не в ответе ajax, как было раньше.